# Find the B and tell me what you see

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus

**What trio is hidden below? Explain your reasoning.**

---

[image]

```
                 Find the B and tell me what you see
        

                              __ ____
                             ___ ______
                            ____ ___
                            ____ _____
                            ____ ____
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The trio hidden below are:

> The **[BEE GEES](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bee_Gees)**

Reason

Firstly

> Identify the rebuses: from left to right you get… GO, GAME, AGE, IGNITE, CAGE, GIN, RAGE, IGLOO, LEGS AND GEAR

Next

> Fill in the letters underneath in that order and and draw over the letter Gs to find ‘the B’ like so:

> [image]

Hence you have

> The **BEE GEES**!

Comment: Great job, this is the answer!

Comment: Oh my goodness. I once thought I was smart, but now realize I'm not even close.